# Actions for creating venv in python and clone a git repo

Tags: python, git, github

I'm relatively new in all that and I have a problem with the row of the actions. Say that you created a directory and you want a python virtual environment for some project and clone a few git repos (say, from GitHub). Then you `cd` in that directory and create a virtual environment using the `venv` module (for python3). To do so you run the following command,

```py
     python3 -m venv my_venv
```

which will create in your directory a virtual environment called my_env. To activate this environment you run the following.

```py
     source ./my_env/bin/activate
```

If in addition inside that directory you have a requirements.txt file you can run,

```py
     pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
```

to install your various dependencies and packages with [pip3](/questions/tagged/pip3). Now this is where I'm getting confused. If you want to clone git repos where exactly you do that? In the same directory you just run `git clone` and creates the git repos or you need to `cd` in another folder. In order to let python venv pick up the cloned repos is the above enough, or venv must be installed after you have cloned the repos in your directory?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand what is virtual environments, when you understand what it is for, the order of actions will be more clear.

> Python applications will often use packages and modules that don’t come as part of the standard library. Applications will sometimes need a specific version of a library, because the application may require that a particular bug has been fixed or the application may be written using an obsolete version of the library’s interface.
>
> This means it may not be possible for one Python installation to meet the requirements of every application. If application A needs version 1.0 of a particular module but application B needs version 2.0, then the requirements are in conflict and installing either version 1.0 or 2.0 will leave one application unable to run.
>
> The solution for this problem is to create a virtual environment, a self-contained directory tree that contains a Python installation for a particular version of Python, plus a number of additional packages.
>
> Different applications can then use different virtual environments. To resolve the earlier example of conflicting requirements, application A can have its own virtual environment with version 1.0 installed while application B has another virtual environment with version 2.0. If application B requires a library be upgraded to version 3.0, this will not affect application A’s environment.

※ Reference: [12. Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

---

Generally, the following order is the most appropriated.

1. `$ git clone <Project A>  # Cloning project repository`
2. `$ cd <Project A> # Enter to project directory`
3. `$ python3 -m venv my_venv # If not created, creating virtualenv`
4. `$ source ./my_venv/bin/activate # Activating virtualenv`
5. `(my_venv)$ pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt # Installing dependencies`
6. `(my_venv)$ deactivate # When you want to leave virtual environment`

All installed dependencies at step 5 will be unavailable after you leave virtual environment.

Comment: thanks for your reply. when you want to go back to your virtual environment? how do you activate it? Is the "state" of your environment as it was before you deactivate?

Comment: Added comments in answer.

Comment: unfortunately I can't upvote your answer, but would be +1 :). cheers

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: just one last question. when you have deactivated your venv and want to activate it again to carry on your project, do you repeat step 4?

Comment: Just try to play with activate deactivate and pop install. And look hot it behave.

Comment: Step 4+| has a spelling error: `$ source ./my_env/bin/activate # Activating virtualenv`, it should be: `$ source ./my_venv/bin/activate # Activating virtualenv` At least if you want to stay consistent with the naming :)

Comment: should the virtual env dir be committed to git?

Answer (score 0):

source ./my_venv/bin/activate # Activating virtualenv

what do you mean by source in this. can  we use step like below

my_venv/Scripts/activate.bat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Environment Creation might be confusing: Extending on @Yeheshuah's answer, there are differences between unix systems and windows systems when creating activating virtual environments.

All the steps except for step 4 are identical.

**Activation on Linux/MacOS**

Having navigated the console to the project directory in step two where the venv was created in step 3, activate it through the terminal using the command

```
source ./my_venv/bin/activate
```

One might as well activate the venv from a different location by providing the whole path:

```
source <Project A>/my_venv/bin/activate
```

**Activation on Windows**

On windows, the activation is different. The following steps assume you have navigated to the project directory:

1. Using the standard terminal `cmd.exe`: type the command `.\env\Scripts\activate.bat` to activate the venv
2. Using `powershell.exe`: type the command `.\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1` to activate the venv

If the virtual environment was installed with **conda**, it can be activated with powershell from any location using the command `conda activate my_venv`.